# Django ORM get data by pagination in query level?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, orm

I'm using Django ORM to get Employee modal data, but I have 1000-2000 data of employees in that table, now I want to get only one-page data at a time, for this raw query for 2nd page work like:

```
SELECT * FROM employee LIMIT 30 OFFSET 60;
```

and its ORM version is like this:

```
page_number = 3
records_per_page = 30
offset = (page_number - 1) * records_per_page
employees = Employee.objects.all().order_by('id')[offset:offset+records_per_page]
```

I want to know if is this correct to use when a large number of data. Because here it gets `Employee.objects.all()` and then it `offset` records or it's working principle is different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is correct because Django ORM is lazy so when we call Employee.objects.all() it simply stores the query `SELECT * FROM employee` in the memory but does not execute it until you decide to use the object and when you set the offset/limit it change the query stored in the memory to this `SELECT * FROM employee LIMIT 30 OFFSET 60;` so this means that .all() will never run.

Comment: @Cairo this means, Employee.objects.all().order_by('id')[offset:offset+records_per_page] also not overload when too many records ?

Comment: yes exactly thanks for Django ORM lazy feature